# How do I know the width and height transhipped content in span (div) block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a block:

```
<span id="xCUBE"></span>
```

Which overloaded by timer:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function show() {
   $.ajax({
       url: "/table/" + Math.floor(Math.random() * ( 999 )) + "/",
       cache: false,
       success: function(html){
           $("#xCUBE").html(html);
           }
       });
   }

$(document).ready(function(){
    show();
    setInterval('show()',500);
    });
</script>
```

In this block id="xCUBE" built table and need to check it is placed in the current window or not. That is, find the actual width of the window and width of the block, compare, and if the table is wider than the screen, ask for a shorter or narrower table. If you ask the width of the box and a window on the forehead, I get the width and height 0:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function doResize( ) {
   $('body').append('<div>Win WxH=  ' + $(window).width()
          + 'x' + $(window).height() + ' (table WxH = '
          + $("#xCUBE").width() + 'x' + $("#xCUBE").height()
          +')</div>');
   }

$(function() {
   doResize();
   $(window).resize(doResize);
   });
</script>
```

Script does not see dynamic content of table inside id="xCUBE". How to get width and height of reloadable content?

Comment: Hard to say without a functioning example, but I'd guess you need to be doing your size checks on the ajax success callback, after the dom has been modified. On document ready, the table would be empty, I assume

Answer (score 0):

shouldn´t you just resize after new content is appended ?

```
function show() {
   $.ajax({
       url: "/table/" + Math.floor(Math.random() * ( 999 )) + "/",
       cache: false,
       success: function(html){
           //do resize and pass the content
           doResize(html);
           }
       });
}


function doResize(html) {
   //append to target and measure while its not visible (but still has sizes)
   $("#xCUBE").html('<div style="visibility:hidden">'+html+'</div>');
   //remember them
   cubeWidth= $("#xCUBE").width();
   cubeheight=$("#xCUBE").heigth();
   //empty that thing
   $("#xCUBE").empty()
   //append your  WxH=? stuff, i hae no idea
   $('body').append('<div>Win WxH=  ' + $(window).width()
          + 'x' + $(window).height() + ' (table WxH = '
          + cubeWidth + 'x' + cubeheight
          +')</div>');
   //and finally append the visible content
   $("#xCUBE").html(html);
}


$(document).ready(function(){
     //call show initially
     show();
     var k= setInterval('show()',500);
     $(window).resize(function(){
       //clear and reset interval and show imediatly, this could create thousands of ajax requests maybe some throttle, google it
       clearInterval(k);
       show();
       k=setInterval('show()',500);
     });
     });
    });
```

updated

Comment: Overloaded content regardless of resizing

If a windows resized, have to check the size table and compare with the size of the window... to change something in the query "/table/". But I did not get to know the size of the table inside "xCUBE"

Comment: Out of action
"Win WxH" and "table WxH" not printed... ^(